# Scanning double with nextDouble

Tags: java, double

I'm learning Java and I got some problems when I try input double floating numbers.

Like this.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Program {
     public static void main (String[] args) {
           Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
           double number = inp.nextDouble();
           System.out.println(number);
     }
}
```

If I enter *1000* my output will be *1000.0*. But if I enter *1000.0*, I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2456)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:6)
Java Result: 1
```

How could I solve this?

Comment: What if you enter `1000,0`?

Comment: @MarounMaroun I think it depends on the country where you are. I'm in Italy and decimal numbers are written with a comma, not a dot, so if i enter `1000.0` i get an `InputMismatchException`, if i enter `1000,0` everything goes fine.

Comment: yeah I also heard this that in france `,` works as `.` in numbers , @BackSlash with which locale you checked it ?

Comment: @sansix I checked with the default locale, which is `Locale.ITALY` for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely due to Locale differences between 1000.0 and 1000,0... so you could try this:

```
Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
inp.useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Scanner doesn't have such method, it's `useLocale`

Comment: But there is a a problem.
    cannot find symbol:
       symbol: variable Locale
       location: class Program
    ----

Comment: @Alvadorn You have to import `java.util.Locale`

Comment: @BackSlash Thanks for pointing out my typo. Alvadorn - glad it works!